# How to determine which app is running on the Touch Bar in MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar

Every time I unlock my 2018 15" MacBook Pro, the Touch Bar displays a `x` button and the `Esc` button, irrespective of whatever the Mac is running (it is not displaying the address toolbar on Chrome for example). I must always touch the `x` button to remove it, and display the current content for the Touch Bar.

I checked for running applications with system monitor, and nothing was wrong.

Is there a way to know what is currently controlling the Touch bBar? I want to delete this, and I cannot find it.

Comment: BetterTouchTool app will do that.

Comment: This is exactly it! I was already using BetterTouchTool, and I don't know why, but a shortcut was there, empty... I just removed it and my problem is solved! :D
I'm still intrigued on how to know what is running on the Touch Bar tough...

Comment: Great, one problem solved.

Comment: can you post a screen shot of your touch bar `Control + Command + Shift + 6` will take a screen shot of it.

Comment: This is not relevant anymore. It just raised the question if one program is able to control the Touch Bar like BetterTouchTool, how to know what program is currently using the Touch Bar? In this case, it was simple, but is case it's an other tool, I'm not going to guess every opened application, there is surely a way to know

Comment: OK, then we are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BetterTouchTool app could take control of your Touch bar.

Disable or remove it.